# Update state in context when starting the application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So basically I already i Have 2 main components, Home And Front(Weather App). I using geolocation and for now when i route from my Home to Front page its take a 2 second to get a geolocation from user so my Front page load with some empty information and after 2 second my page update with data.. So I wanna to get and update my State on the beginning when I run my app and my Home Component shows up.

Context:

```html
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {promiseLocation} from '../components/Location'
import axios from 'axios'

const KEY = 'fdc0a9d5321ee73e70535ed7d7e052ce'

export const InitialWeatherContext = createContext();
const InitialWeatherContextProvider = props => {
    const [initialWeather, setInitial] = useState({
      city: null,
      temp: null,
      feels: null
    });
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchLocation = async () => {
        const { coords } = await promiseLocation();
        const response = await axios(
          `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${coords.latitude}&lon=${coords.longitude}&appid=${KEY}&units=metric`
        );
        setInitial({
          city: response.data.name,
          temp: response.data.main.temp,
          feels: response.data.main.feels_like
        });
      };
      fetchLocation();
    }, []);
    // ...
    
    return (
      <InitialWeatherContext.Provider value={{initialWeather}}>
        {props.children}
      </InitialWeatherContext.Provider>
    );
  };


export default InitialWeatherContextProvider
```

Front:

```html
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import { InitialWeatherContext } from '../context/InitialWeatherContext'

const Front =  () => {
  
const {initialWeather} = useContext(InitialWeatherContext)
console.log(initialWeather)
    return (
        <div className='front'>
            <div className='date-city-data-wrap'>
                <div className='date-name'>
                    <p className='date'>March 13</p>
                    <h1 className='city'>{initialWeather.city}</h1>
                </div>
                <div className='data'>
                    <div className='temp'>
                        <h1>Helo</h1>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div className='data-info-wrap rain'>
                        <div className='icon rain-icon'>
                            <i className="fas fa-ad"></i>
                            <p>humidity</p>
                        </div>
                        <h1>40%</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className='data-info-wrap wind'>
                        <div className='icon wind-icon'>
                            <i className="fas fa-ad"></i>
                            <p>humidity</p>
                        </div>
                        <h1>8 km/h</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className='data-info-wrap humidity'>
                        <div className='icon humidity-icon'>
                            <i className="fas fa-ad"></i>
                            <p>humidity</p>
                        </div>
                        <h1>5%</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className='data-info-wrap humidity'>
                        <div className='icon humidity-icon'>
                            <i className="fas fa-ad"></i>
                            <p>humidity</p>
                        </div>
                        <h1>5%</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Front
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the `useEffect` in the provider itself.

```
const InitialWeatherContextProvider = props => {
  const [initialWeather, setInitial] = useState({
    city: null,
    temp: null,
    feels: null
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLocation = async () => {
      const { coords } = await promiseLocation();
      const response = await axios(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${coords.latitude}&lon=${coords.longitude}&appid=${KEY}&units=metric`
      );
      setInitial({
        city: response.data.name,
        temp: response.data.main.temp,
        feels: response.data.main.feels_like
      });
    };

    fetchLocation();
  }, []);

  // ...
  return (
    <InitialWeatherContext.Provider value={{ initialWeather, fillData }}>
      {props.children}
    </InitialWeatherContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Ofc I imported necessary components and api keys

Comment: It doesnt show from other reason, cant guess without reproducible example.

Comment: Okey it's weird but now It works but I didn't change anything, It is possible that free weather api has something like delay or i dont know maximum data for a time? I update code so u can look :D

Comment: I dont know, just answered what you asked.

Comment: Also When I am on Front Component and I refresh the page sometime i have wait 1-2 seconds to update and shows data.

Comment: Well, you try to fetch the data, it doesn't happen instantly, it is also an async request. Usually, you should show some indication (loading spinner etc). Check network tab in devtools for the timing